# Conditional formatting if an input cell is blank in a row marked completed

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight any blank input cell in a row if the row is labeled as completed in column B.  There are several columns with information being entered in them and I would like to use this as a flag for accidentally leaving a blank when completing a row.

I tried entering formula below for conditional formatting rule, but it didn't work.

```
=AND($B2="completed", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track! The first condition in your `AND` function is correct. But for the second one, you need to specify which cell it should compare `""` with. `""` by itself is not a condition. Try this (assuming your conditional format is being applied to a range of cells starting at cell `A2`):

```
=AND($B2="completed", A2="")
```